# Number of solutions of a trigonometric equation depending on the value of n

Tags: trigonometry

> Question:  For each integral $n$, find the number of solutions of $2x=(2n+1)×{\pi}(1-\cos x)$

I tried to solve first by simplifying then by using graphs of known equations.
On simplifying I got $$\frac{x}{(2n+1)×{\pi}} = \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}$$ Then the right hand side (if plotted separately) of the equation is a straight line with slope $$\frac{1}{(2n+1)×{\pi}}$$. The LHS has the following graph:-[image: graph of $sin^2 x/2$]

My idea is that the solutions will be at the intersection of the graph of LHS & RHS. On checking cases for $n=1$  i found there are 3 solutions , for $n=2$  i found there are 5 solutions .
[image: intersection of graphs for n=1]

My claim is that for every n there are     $2n+1$ solutions, since by observation there is there is one intersection of the graph of LHS and RHS has exactly $1$ intersection between $x= (k-1)\pi$ and 
$k\pi$ for all $k \leq 2n+1$ ,an integer. But answer is given exactly $2n+3$ solutions. Is my claim wrong or it has any flaw? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, in the last paragraph, you appeared to write $(k - 1) \times /\pi$.  What did you actually mean?

Comment: My question is 2x=(2n+1)×pi(1-cosx)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig for example n=1 we get a solution between \pi and 2\pi as shown in graph.

Comment: Moreover my question is why can't we solve graphically?

Answer (score 0):

i would write the equation in the form
$$2x+\frac{2n+1}{\pi}\cos(x)-\frac{2n+1}{\pi}=0$$
when we define $$f(x)=2x+\frac{2n+1}{\pi}\cos(x)-\frac{2n+1}{\pi}$$ then we get
$$f'(x)=0$$ if $$\sin(x)=\frac{2\pi}{2n+1}$$ and we have that $$|\sin(x)|\le 1$$

Comment: My question  was wrongly edited by others. Please see the correct quetion and help me.